# Proving that $A\setminus B\subseteq C$ implies $A\setminus C\subseteq B$ .

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Theorem. Suppose $A, B$, and $C$ are sets, and $A\setminus B\subseteq C$. Then $A\setminus C\subseteq B$ .

What I tried

Proof:

My try:

From the statement $A\setminus C\subseteq B$

We infer that $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$ means $x\in B$

Hence by contradiction, we assume that

$x\notin B$

The statement then becomes

$x\in A\setminus B$ and $x\notin C$ but it contradicts with $A\setminus B\subseteq C$ since it implies $x\in C$. Is my try correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't see a proof of this statement in your answer. You want to prove that $X\subseteq Y$. The simplest way of doing so, would be element chasing. The proof method is as follows,

1. Let $x\in X$ be some arbitrary element.
2. Analyze what it means for $x$ to be in $X$.
3. Make inferences based on that analysis [contradictions and contrapositive parts could be also made here].
4. Conclude that $x\in Y$.

So in this case, you would have to take some $x\in A\setminus C$, conclude that $x\in A$ but $x\notin C$. Assume towards contradiction that $x\notin B$, therefore $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, so $x\in A\setminus B$ ... [and I'll let you finish this yourself].

Comment: My second try: 

From the statement $A\setminus C\subseteq B$

We infer that $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$ means $x\in B$

Hence by contradiction, we assume that 

 $x\notin B$

The statement then becomes 

$x\in A\setminus B$ and $x\notin C$ but it contradicts with $A\setminus B\subseteq C$ since it implies $x\in C$. Is my second try correct. Thanks

Comment: Just for sake of clarity, you should begin by stating that $x\in A\setminus C$. It looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Given $A\setminus B\subseteq C$.

But $ A\subseteq A\cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup B\subseteq  C\cup B$

$\therefore A\subseteq C\cup B\implies A\setminus C\subseteq B $.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use boolean algebra.

For element $x$, relation $A\setminus B\subseteq C$ means $((x\in A) \wedge \neg(x\in B))\to (x\in C)$. Denote $a=x\in A$, $b=x\in B$, $c=x\in C$. We have a formula:
$$
(a\bar b)\to c\equiv \overline{a\bar b}\vee c \equiv \bar a\vee b\vee c.
$$
(overline means negation, of course). Let's rearrange items:
$$
\bar a\vee b\vee c = (\bar a\vee c) \vee b = \overline{a\bar c}\vee b \equiv (a\bar c)\to b,
$$
or $((x\in A) \wedge \neg(x\in C))\to (x\in B)$, which equivalent to $A\setminus C\subseteq B$.

Comment: That's not 'formal logic', that's Boolean algebra. It's fine, but it's not 'formal logic'.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, ok, i'll edit. it's my russian english) By "formal" I meant that it's not require anything except algrebraic manipulation

Comment: I bet your English Russian is better. :-)

Comment: Is my way of doing also correct?

Comment: @yswong, I think no. See first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your theorem as follows: If $x \in A \setminus C$ and $A \setminus B \subseteq C$, then $x \in B$. And you can prove it as follows.

Let $x \in A \setminus C$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \not\in C$. $x \not\in C$ implies that $x$ is not in $A \setminus B$. If $x$ is in $A$, but is not in $A \setminus B$, then $x$ must be in $B$ and therefore, $x \in B$, what completes the proof. $\square$